# Formula for consecutive residue of primitive modulo n.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

\begin{align*}
3^0 \equiv 1\mod 7\\
3^1 \equiv 3\mod 7\\
3^2 \equiv 2\mod 7\\
3^3 \equiv 6\mod 7\\
3^4 \equiv 4\mod 7\\
3^5 \equiv 5\mod 7\\
3^6 \equiv 1\mod 7\\
3^7 \equiv 3\mod 7\\
\end{align*}

Now just focusing on 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1....
How to devise a formula to find the next number.
Like if 2 is given how to find 6 or if 4 is given how to find 5?
I am looking for an explicit function.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat says $3^{6k+r}$mod$7=3^r$mod$7,0\le r \le 5$. Up to $r=5$ the calculation is very simple, no?

Comment: How do you actually go about calculating it? I am not familiar with modular arithmetic. I needed it for application purpose.

Comment: It's the remainder in long division.

Comment: Can you give an example from above?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply by $3$ and take the residue mod $7$. This is because $3^j$ mod $7$ is the same as $3^{j-1}\cdot 3$ mod $7$.

Comment: These were my initial thoughts, but, you aren't really giving a formula; you are giving a recursive relationship.

Comment: The OP has the formula; they are just taking powers of $3$. The question states "How to devise a formula to get the next number," which a recursive formula is fine for

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it was of help. But isn't there a formula where you have an input variable and an output variable?

Comment: Yes, technically you are right, but this is obvious by definition. A recursive formula *would* work, but would probably not help the OP.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a direct non-recursive formula. What would help is taking the power mod $\phi(7) = 6$.

Comment: I was actually looking for an explicit function.

Comment: **As far as I know**, that is not possible.

Comment: @user469405, you wrote in your original post "How to devise a formula to find the next number. Like if 2 is given how to find 6 or if 4 is given how to find 5?"; perhaps this was not the best way to let people know that you were looking for an explicit function. Could you please edit/rephrase your question?

Comment: Okay sure, I will.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like modulus calculations, you could use:
For odd $a_k:\quad a_{k+1} = (7-a_k)/2$
For even $a_k:\quad a_{k+1} = 7-a_k/2$

Comment: Thank you! But how did you devise this? I want to use it for other primitives and modulos.

Comment: Yes they work universally, thank you again. I am still curious how you devised it but nevermind. Also, I guess you can not merge them both into one?

Comment: Can we find the nth number from a given number directly this way? Like if 3 is given can we get 5 from it given that it is the fourth number below or second number above.

Comment: I think it works only for "modulo = 2.factor + 1" like "7 = 2.3 + 1".

Comment: Yes, it relies to some extent on $2\cdot 3\equiv -1 \bmod 7$ but also on $7$ being a rather small number, with the inevitable lack of complexity that gives.

Comment: Can we have a function to find any element  given its position from a given element? Like given 3 and 4 steps down, we get 5.